# How to move a file based on file name using a batch file?

Tags: batch-file

OK, I just made this file mover and it moves the files with matching file names.

```
move "03 Extracted\Files\1 *.txt" "06 Edit Files\Files 1\"
```

This works great and this was easy.

But how do I move files that don't have matching names?

```
1 - dog.txt
5 - cat.txt
10 - birds.txt
45 - seats.txt
152 - rooms.txt
```

I would like to keep it simple. I'm thinking the easiest would be to read the numbers at the beginning of the file name.

```
move "03 Extracted\* - *.txt" "06 Edit Files\Files 1-9\"
move "03 Extracted\** - *.txt" "06 Edit Files\Files 10-99\"
move "03 Extracted\*** - *.txt" "06 Edit Files\Files 100-999\"
```

I want to move files based on the numbers in front of the filename, and into the right number folders.

How could this be written?

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, with `dir` the wildcard `?` means "zero or one character".
Gladly, with `where`, the wildcard `?` means "exactly one character".
That helps with building matching patterns:

```
@echo off
setlocal 

set "folder=03 Extracted\Files"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('where /r "%folder%" "? -*"') do ECHO move "%%a" "Files 1-9\"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('where /r "%folder%" "?? -*"') do ECHO move "%%a" "Files 10-99\"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('where /r "%folder%" "??? -*"') do ECHO move "%%a" "Files 100-999\"
```

NOTE: I "disarmed" the `move` commands by just echoing it. Remove the `ECHO`'s when it does what you want.

Before:

```
D:.
│   test.bat
│
├───03 Extracted
│   └───Files
│          1 - dog.txt
│          10 - birds.txt
│          152 - rooms.txt
│          45 - seats.txt
│          5 - cat.txt

├───Files 1-9
│
├───Files 10-99
│
└───Files 100-999
```

After:

```
D:.
│   test.bat
│
├───03 Extracted
│   └───Files
├───Files 1-9
│       1 - dog.txt
│       5 - cat.txt
│
├───Files 10-99
│       10 - birds.txt
│       45 - seats.txt
│
└───Files 100-999
        152 - rooms.txt
```